# Memory Usage by Bytes Top 10

Tags: memory, top

I need a way to see how many bytes to top ten processes are using not percentage.
I am using centos

Comment: Your question is vague and ambiguous. Are you asking about *physical* memory?

Comment: yes, I want to know how many bytes the top programs are using so I can monitor it over time and figure out why the resources are growing and  on what.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it would be better to use ps with head

```
ps aux --sort -rss | head -10
```

The `RSS` field shows physical memory usage in KB.

Comment: This displays memory percentage. I would really like to see how many bytes in KB or MB.

Comment: no look on the rss column

Comment: is -rss bytes? KB? MB?

Comment: it is in KB that is your resident memory

Comment: This seems like your answer. The 'RSS' field has your answer in KB.

Comment: yea KB is fine i can divide it out to show as MB and GB. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I just notice that `rss` is in kiloBytes.

I created an `awk` script to print sizes in human readable format:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk

{
    hr[1024**2]="GB"; hr[1024]="MB";
    for (x=1024**3; x>=1024; x/=1024) {
        if ($1>=x) {
            printf ("%-6.1f %s ", $1/x, hr[x]); break
        }
    }
}
{ printf ("%-6s %-10s ", $2, $3) }
{ for ( x=4 ; x<=NF ; x++ ) { printf ("%s ",$x) } print ("") }
```

and pipe the `ps` output to:

`$ ps --no-headers -eo rss,pid,user,command --sort -rss | head -10 | awk -f topmem.awk`

Answer (score 2):

`top` and hit `M` sorts by resident memory usage.  Quickest and easiest I know of.